# React Native - JSON. Как получить значение через API не списком?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, react-native, fetch

React Native (17.0.2) чистый, без `axios` и т.п., пытаюсь сделать c помощью `fetch`.

Сам JSON пример

```
{
  "response":"success",
  "value":{
    "name":"test",
    "text":"test"
  },
  "list": [
    { "id": "1", "title": "test", "releaseYear": "1977" },
    { "id": "2", "title": "test", "releaseYear": "1977" }
  ]
}
```

**React Native**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getMovies = async () => {
     try {
      const response = await fetch('https://you_site.com/test.json');
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json.movies);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>

    {/* Тут нужно отобразить value->name */}

      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Выводит только список из массива `list`, всё работает как нужно.

Но как мне вывести и отобразить значение из ключа `name` из объекта `value` сразу после `<View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>` один раз перед всем списком (т.е. отобразить `test`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено! Данный код не идеален - но он решает поставленную задачу.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [test, setTest ] = useState([]);

  const getMovies = async () => {
     try {
      const response = await fetch('https://itstav.ru/1.json');
      const json = await response.json();
      setTest (json.value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      <Text>{test.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: все в порядке с кодом. Неплохо было бы иметь пару пояснений, что не так делали с самого начала и как нашли решение

Comment: Нужно читать документацию и смотреть больше курсов, просто новичёк и полез в глубь без базовых знаний. Как нашёл решение - человек с другого форума помог (дал наводку) а дальше мозгами и методом проб и ошибок :)

Comment: Да я про код ваш. Следующий за вами, кто будет искать ответ на такой же вопрос потратит меньше времени и сил. =) А для вас тренировка в понимании вашего кода и объяснении другим

Comment: Согласен с Вами полностью на все 100%! Самое главное для других - это уже готовый ответ который поможет! 